# javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Missing configuration resource for path /WEB-INF/struts-config.xml

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, struts

I am new to Struts and I am trying to run a sample login web-application using Struts but I am unable to get the result due to `(javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Missing configuration resource for path /WEB-INF/struts-config.xml)` the error. I had done everything in configuring struts in eclipse. I even don't no what the exception is? please anyone help me

**the errors I am getting are:**

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Missing configuration resource for path /WEB-INF/struts-config.xml
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.splitAndResolvePaths(ActionServlet.java:1872)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(ActionServlet.java:683)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:356)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

**`index.jsp`:**

```
<html> 
    <body>


        <form action="login.do">
       <tr>
       <td>Username</td> 
       <td><input type = "text" name = "username" maxlength = "25"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>Password</td>
       <td><input type = "password" name = "password" minlength = "8" maxlength = "16"></td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td  colspan = "2" align = "center"><button type = "submit" name = "submit">Submit</button>
       <button type = "reset"   name = "reset">Reset</button></td>

       </tr>


        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**`LoginForm.java`:**

```
package com.sample.com;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class LoginAction extends Action {

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    {
        System.out.println("test");

    LoginForm login = (LoginForm)form;

    String uname=login.getUname();

    String pass=login.getPass();

    if(uname=="admin" && pass =="test")
    {
    return mapping.findForward("success");

    }
    else
    {
    return mapping.findForward("failure");

    }
  }
}
```

**`LoginAction.java`:**

```
package com.sample.com;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



public class LoginAction extends Action {

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    {

        System.out.println("test");

    LoginForm login = (LoginForm)form;

    String uname=login.getUname();

    String pass=login.getPass();

    if(uname=="admin" && pass =="test")
    {
    return mapping.findForward("success");
    }
    else
    {
    return mapping.findForward("failure");

    }

  }


}
```

**`config-struts.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>



<struts-config>

    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="loginRequest" type="com.sample.com.LoginForm"/>
    </form-beans> 

    <global-forwards>
        <forward name="success"  path="/success.jsp"/>
    </global-forwards>

    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/login" type="com.sample.com.LoginAction" name="loginRequest">
            <forward name="success" path="/success.jsp"/>
            <forward name="failure" path="/failure.jsp"/>        
        </action>
    </action-mappings>

</struts-config>
```

**`web.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>2</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>detail</param-name>
            <param-value>2</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Please share your package structure.

Comment: Did you EVER get any solution for this error?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `struts-config.xml` resides in WEB-INF folder. Similarly, `hibernate.cfg.xml` should also be at the appropriate place(if you are using it).

Answer (score 1):

You are configured the web application to use `struts-config.xml`

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>config</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

but there's not the file with such name in the specified folder. Make sure the file exist there or if you use another name for the struts configuration file you could change this init param value to reflect the file availability. If you have several configuration files each for the module, you could use a comma to separate names.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the *servlet-api.jar* from the apache *lib* folder. You need to include the *struts.xml* folder in *src* folder under java resources.

Answer (score 0):

1) You have mentioned your struts.xml filename as **config-struts.xml** but in the init-param you wrote as **struts-config.xml**. Please check the names properly.

2) Or maybe (common issue) because you are missing the DTD tag in your struts xml file. Try to add this code above the `<struts-config>` tag in your **struts-config.xml**.

`<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
       "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">`